# What aircraft was I flying in?

Tags: aircraft-design

In 1989 I was taking my first flying lesson. We were in a plane that had a low wing single engine and 2 seats if I recall correctly. After taking off on my first lesson the instructor was talking about radio and navigation settings and when retrieving a manual hit the door latch with his elbow and the door flew up and bent the tub connect to the frame of the plane. The hinges ripped out of the frame and was severely bent preventing it from being closed for about 6 ".He held the door while I flew the plane under his careful instruction ..I had flown hundreds of hours on a computer flight simulator on my home PC. Nevertheless he held the door while I navigated back to our original take off location in Lincoln park, nj...when back in the area he resumed control of plan while I reached across him to hold the door. He dropped the plane down and we landed safely.  Can anyone name the aircraft manufacturer and model...I want to write a story about my first flying lesson and need to know that info ..thx Frank

Comment: How it could be the instructor did not tell the model of the aircraft?

Comment: Perhaps you could give more hints? There are very many low wing single engine 2-seat aircrafts, many of whom had accidents at one point or another. Perhaps color, where you flew from or any other information (registration perhaps?) would help. However with the currently given information, I fear that the question cannot be answered...

Comment: What does your log book call it?  (could be a Piper Tomahawk or Beechcraft Skipper)

Comment: Was it fabric covered or metal?

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling this never happened, except maybe in that simulator...

Comment: @JuanJimenez Hundreds of simulator hours on a home PC in 1989? Everything about this question seems a bit of a fantasy "memory". Those were the days of 1.2MB floppy disks and Oregon Trail on a green monochrome. RAM was well above $200 per MiB(Not adjusted to 2022 dollars)

Comment: @MaxPower MS Flight Simulator 1.0 was released in 1982 for the IBM PC. It was in version 3.0 in 1988. I probably had hundreds of hours on it by 1989. I also got my PPSEL in Jan 89 after 6 months training in Beech Skipper. From his description, I would think it was not a Skipper. The lower rear door latches were very unreliable, but there was a single overhead latch that grabbed both doors very securely. Realistically though, if the latches get popped when flying, the door just opens an inch or so and makes lots of noise. It's on the ground that the door can be damaged by a gust of wind.